# Combine multiple row to single row for unique values in multiple column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get unique rows based on unique values on multiple columns in SQL Server 2012.

### Source Data:

UserId  ---- P1 ---- P2 ------ P3

---

101  ------- NO ---- NO ------- YES

101  ------- NO ---- YES ------ NO

101  ------- YES ---- NO ------- NO

102 -------- NO ----- NO ------- NO

My source data has 'YES' in single columns for multiple rows.

I'm trying to get the result as follows:

### Desired Output:

UserId  ---- P1 ---- P2 ------ P3

---

101  ------- YES ---- YES ----- YES

102 -------- NO ----- NO ------- NO

Any ideas or code-sample will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So YES also takes precedence over NO? Thus if you had R1-1 = NO NO NO and R1-2 = YES NO NO then you would be YES NO NO?  Are there any other values of which to be aware?

Comment: Just YES and NO alone. Need to combine with UserId, (R1, R2, R3,...) based on single row for UserId

Comment: if none of the answer is correct then we need more explanation or few more example ?what id 102 had one yes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **SQL Server 2012** and higher you can use this construction:

```
SELECT  UserId,
        IIF(SUM(IIF(P1 = 'YES',1,0)) > 0,'YES','NO') as P1,
        IIF(SUM(IIF(P2 = 'YES',1,0)) > 0,'YES','NO') as P2,
        IIF(SUM(IIF(P3 = 'YES',1,0)) > 0,'YES','NO') as P3
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY UserId
```

Or, instead of [IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql) use [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) (**SQL Server 2008** or higher):

```
SELECT  UserId,
        CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN P1 = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as P1,
        CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN P2 = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as P2,
        CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN P3 = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as P3
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY UserId
```

Output:

```
UserId  P1  P2  P3
101     YES YES YES
102     NO  NO  NO
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case (handling only `YES` and `NO` values) simple `MIN`/`MAX` can solve the task.

```
DECLARE @SourceData TABLE
(
    [UserId] INT
   ,[P1] VARCHAR(3)
   ,[P2] VARCHAR(3)
   ,[P3] VARCHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO @SourceData ([UserId], [P1], [P2], [P3])
VALUES ('101', 'NO', 'NO', 'YES')
      ,('101', 'NO', 'YES', 'NO')
      ,('101', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO')
      ,('102', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO');

SELECT [UserId]
      ,MAX([P1])
      ,MAX([P2])
      ,MAX([P3])
FROM @SourceData
GROUP By [UserId];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT
      DISTINCT UserId
  FROM T1
)
SELECT
UserId,
P1 = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T1 WHERE UserId = CTE.UserId AND P1='YES')
THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END,
P2 = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T1 WHERE UserId = CTE.UserId AND P2='YES')
THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END,
P3  = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T1 WHERE UserId = CTE.UserId AND P3='YES')
THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
FROM CTE
```

Note : Assuming your table name as T1